# Add existing object to list

Tags: c#, list

I have an `Order` class which contains a `List<Album>` property. In initialization I have a list of `Albums`:

```
var albums = new List<Album>
{
    new Album { ArtistId = 2, GenreId = 2, Price = 9.99m, Title = "Mine is Yours" },
    new Album { ArtistId = 2, GenreId = 2, Price = 9.99m, Title = "Robbers & Cowards" },
    new Album { ArtistId = 2, GenreId = 2, Price = 9.99m, Title = "Hold My Home" }
};
```

Next I have a list of `Orders`:

```
var orders = new List<Orders>
{
    new Orders { Albums = //code}
};
```

What I want to do is be able to add albums from the `albums` list to the `Albums` property. Essentially I don't want to be writing `Albums = {new Album{//code},{//more code}}`. I want to write something like `Albums = {{AlbumId = 1}, {AlbumId = 2}}`. Etc to add existing albums to the list.

Apologies if badly worded.

Comment: Do you want to add all the items in `albums` or only some?

Comment: Some, for example if I wanted the album titled "Robbers & Cowards",  i would put something like new Orders {Albums = {AlbumId = 2}};

Comment: Is the `Albums` property of type `List<Album>`?

Comment: If the `Albums` property is of type `List<Album>`  you can simply write `new Orders {Albums = albums}`

Comment: Yeah "public List<Album> Albums { get; set; } = new List<Album>();"

Comment: Do you want copies of the items in `albums`, or do you want to just copy the reference to the items in `albums`? The difference is that if you copy the reference, then any changes in the `Album` items in `albums` will also be reflected in `orders.Albums`, whereas if you copy the item itself (deep copy), then it is independent of the original item.

Comment: Copy the reference

Comment: @maccettura has you covered, then. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this pretty easily using LINQ:

```
var orders = new List<Orders>
{
    new Orders { Albums = albums.Where(x => x.AlbumId == 2 || x.AlbumId == 1).ToList() }
};
```

If you know your ids up front (like in another collection) you could do this:

```
var albumIds = new [] { 1, 2, 4 };
var orders = new List<Orders>
{
    new Orders { Albums = albums.Where(x => albumIds.Contains(x.AlbumId)).ToList() }
};
```

Comment: If property type is List<Album> you should add `.ToList()` after ")"

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Id property in your Album class you can make a dictionary from the initial list you created:

```
var albumsDict = albums.ToDictionary(a => a.Id);
```

Then, you can create your orders list like that:

```
var orders = new List<Orders>
{
    new Orders { Albums = new List<Album>() { albumsDict[1], albumsDict[2], albumsDict[someId] } 
};
```